# Leaflet-Map on Angular does not fit to the screen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet

Every time the Map is loading i am calling 500ms after finished the loading process the `this.map.invalidateSize()`-Method to try to clean the map view up.

But also when I am loading this, the map still appears like this:
[image: Wrong-Displayed Map]

What do i have to do, that the map loads directly in my location or at least in the defined center with the defined zoom-Level?

Is there any event, that I can listen for on Angular/Leaflet, which indicates, that the map has loaded properly and also the loaded KML-Data is loaded?

**EDIT**
The following code is producing this error. Please take note, that i have removed unused content, which is not relevant for this problem (like adding a marker to the map).

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initMap();
}

processBaseLayers() {
  this.layerControl = L.control
    .layers(this.layerControl, null, {
      position: 'bottomright',
    })
    .addTo(this.map);

  let defaultLayerSet = false;

  this.baseLayers.forEach((layer) => {
    const baseLayer = new L.TileLayer(layer.serverURL, {
      maxZoom: layer.maxZoom,
      attribution: layer.attribution,
    });
    if (!defaultLayerSet) {
      baseLayer.addTo(this.map);
      defaultLayerSet = true;
    }
    this.layerControl.addBaseLayer(baseLayer, layer.name);
  });
}

fixMapOccurences() {
  setTimeout(() => { this.map.invalidateSize() }, 500)
}

async initMap() {
  this.map = L.map('map', {
    center: [46.947222222222, 7.4441666666667],
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl: false,
  });

  this.map.whenReady(() => {
    this.processBaseLayers();
    setTimeout(async () => {
      this.fixMapOccurences();
      await this.loadKML();
    }, 1000)
  });
}

async loadKML() {
  this.dataLayers.forEach((dataLayer) => {
    const kmlLayer = omnivore.kml(dataLayer.serverURL).on('ready', () => {
      kmlLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
        if (layer.feature.geometry.type === 'Point') {
          // adding point here
        } else if (layer.feature.geometry.type === 'GeometryCollection') {
          // adding polyline here
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code. It looks for me that you load a list of layers / shapes and then you fit the map bounds to it. And to see all layers, the map have to zoom out completly

Comment: But its not required to zoom out (in my opinion) it is okay, when it just shows the current scope of my location but loads all items in "background" to the map. (See example in question)

Comment: When this is what I think, then you have removed the part from the shared code. I think you calling anywhere `map.fitBounds(....)`. When the map is loaded and you see it like on your screenshot, if you then zoom in, is it going bigger fillup the complete screen or does it stay always in this small rectangle view?

Comment: No, I never call ```fitBounds```. Since this is also not desired. What's funny is that it starts now and then like in the screenshot or then in the upper left corners. When I zoom I can navigate normally on the map. However, this is suboptimal.

Comment: Would it possible for you to create a Demo? Maybe on https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I am sorry, but it does not seem to work to use some of the used plugins. But i can promise i did followed the best-practices by leafletjs.org... So therefore i might just have to wait for an event when the KML and the Map have finished loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230355/discussion-between-dominik-and-falke-design).